# IE crashes when automate testing

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, automated-tests, qtp

We are testing our web application through QTP 12.51 on the IE 11.
We have a report page with couple thousand items. User chan select how many items per page can be (25 by default).
Automation test compares each line of table on report page against database. When the end of table on current page is reached, it clicks "Next Page".
It has 99 pages now. When it goes to approximately 50 pages (it may vary, +/- 5 pgs) the application stops, no link/button/etc on web application works, next page not loading. IE itself becomes slow, but still works. Meanwhile, QTP goes to next record from database and verifies it with first line on the web page which remains the same
While clicking "Next page" manually, nothing crashes.

I tried to change items on the page from 25 to 50, and it crashed on page ~38. Same crashing when 15 items per page.

How that can be fixed?

Comment: I believe it has nothing to do with UFT. I would check with devs on this. Check UFT logs under `"%APPDATA%\Hewlett-Packard\UFT\Logs"`, see if that can shed some lights.

Comment: Maybe you may try to close the browser after 20-25 pages( where it is successful) and retry it from the close page + 1. You may try to check run the script on other browser just in case to narrow down your problem. Does the size of the memory used for IE increases significantly when it stop at page 50 or so then from the start ?

Comment: Unfortunately, to go to page N, I have to click "next page" N-1 times. I tried to only click "next page" till last page without any verifying, and I had no problem. Will try to "next page" till the page I stopped, thnx for idea.

Comment: And yes, the memory increases up to 1.5G and more, both when clicking "next page" manually or by UFT, dependless of the comparing/verifying.
But when manual testing, it does not crash.